# Flutter commands flashes a Command prompt window and it disappears, then command shows nothing

Tags: flutter, dart, command-line, flutter-doctor

really need help,  tried to run flutter doctor on my terminal but it keeps flashing a cmd window, and the flutter command does nothing
am use a dell laptop with windows 10 installed on it

deleted the cache folder,
reinstalled flutter multiple times
have even formatted my laptop multiple times also

Comment: Try to add fluter bin folder to your `Environment Variables` YourFlutterPath\flutter\bin
https://www.alphr.com/environment-variables-windows-10/

Comment: it still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem.

And tested 3 cases.

Case 1)

Make the "flutter" folder in `C:\`

C:\flutter <-- and extract the `flutter_windows_3.7.0-stable.zip`

Success~~

Case 2)

Open the `flutter_windows_3.7.0-stable.zip`
and drag the "flutter folder" into `C:\` with the windows-default extractor.

Success~~

Case 3)

Open the `flutter_windows_3.7.0-stable.zip`
and drag the "flutter folder" into `C:\` with the Bandizip extractor. (3x times faster)

FAILED

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem in my case when I run CMD as Admin the flutter command works just fine so I decided to run android studio as administrator and it solved the problem hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused due to lack of admin privileges, try this:
sign into your microsoft account or create a new one if you don't already have an account, reboot your system, delete the flutter cached folder and run flutter doctor in the terminal, this should fix it (this worked for me on windows 11)